# RMarkdown Error: {r include=FALSE}

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

````
```{r include=FALSE}
x<-3
```
````

When I attempt to Knit HTML with this RMarkdown chunk, I get the following error:

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

What's going on?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can't reproduce (R version 3.3.1)

Comment: That can't be your only bit of R markdown code. You're making an assumption the error is there but it's not.

Comment: It is, I am running it as a test.  When I reload R, I no longer get the error, but the script still shows up in the HTML.  What I am trying to do is just run this in the background with no output.